# How to close selenium drivers while multiprocessing in python on command?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I wrote a python script that uses multiprocessing to open up four different windows and search a common query among them; I'm trying to find a way to close the drivers on command instead of calling driver.close() at the end of the function which would automatically close the drivers as soon as they have successfully spawned.

I would like to browse the windows for a bit and close them when I am finished.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
def main(hosts, inp):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
    driver.get(hosts)
    if 'ebay' in driver.current_url:
        print 'opened ebay'
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('gh-ac')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(inp)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    elif 'google' in driver.current_url:
        print 'opened google'
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('gbqfq')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(inp)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    elif 'etsy' in driver.current_url:
        print 'opened etsy'
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('search-query')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(inp)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    elif 'amazon' in driver.current_url:
        print 'opened amazon'
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(inp)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    else:
        print "--NONE--"

    # driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hosts = ["http://ebay.com", "https://www.google.com/shopping?hl=en", "http://etsy.com", "http://amazon.com"]
    num_hosts = len(hosts)
    inp = raw_input("What do you want to search?: ")
    p = Pool(num_hosts)
    partial_main = partial(main, inp=inp)
    p.map(partial_main, hosts)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
done = raw_input("Type 'done' when finished:" )
    if done = 'done':
        driver.close()
```

but just injected that into main gives me an EOF error

Comment: Why do you not simply call `driver.close()` when you are done?  What is the purpose of waiting for input?

Comment: because I personally want to go through the websites I open. It's a mix of web scraping and 'personal scraping'

Comment: If you put raw input in main() they will be conflict with each other. You should put in body level, but note that you have driver object initialized in each thread and  for this you should initialize driver also in body level and pas to thread, as option.